# Linq Mapping dbml - capturing stored proc parms for error reporting

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

When using the dbml autogeneration in visual studio, a stored procedure call typically ends up looking like this

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="MYDB.ui_index_group_upd")]
    public int ui_index_group_upd([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> group_id, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="VarChar(32)")] string group_code)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), group_id, group_code);
        return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

and this would be typically called like so....

```
  using (var db = new L2SDataContext(base._connectionString))
  {
    var result = db.ui_index_group_upd(1, "foo");
  }
```

This is all fine.

However what i'm trying to achieve is a global way of error trapping and reporting all such method calls in such a way as to record name of proc, and values for all parameters passed in the event of a problem

I'd rather not write specific code proc code for each method and definately don't want to modify autogen code for obvious reasons.

I'm thinking a layer between my call and the dbml method but i though that perhaps someone has encountered a similar issue so I thought I'd put it out there before I spend the day messing about till i get a reasonable answer. I think the trick is a graceful way of enumerating the parms and proc name etc etc

I hope this makes sense, all feedback appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that replacing `MSLinqToSqlGenerator` with something else is the cleanest solution and it might be done in several ways. You could, for example,

1. Use a tool like [T4 Toolbox: LINQ to SQL classes generator](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/01/t4-toolbox-linq-to-sql-classes-generator/) or [Reegenerator](http://www.reegenerator.com/Home.aspx/Features) and modify the provided template to suit your needs. That's probably the easiest way.
2. Generate the code with [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) using a custom template. You will need to create a T4 template which would [use XML data](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/reading-xml-file-t4-templates) from .DBML file. You'd probably need to disable DBML code generation by setting the Custom Tool property to blank. The disadvantage is you will need to run T4 generation each time after modifying .DBML file.
3. Create a [custom tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166817.aspx) to generate the code for you using XML data from .DBML file and some templating solution (T4 or XSLT, perhaps). This approach could arguably be the most flexible one, the only disadvantage is that you'll have to use the custom tool on every developers' machine.

I'm not sure what's optimal for your situation, but I'd probably consider using T4 Toolbox first. The T4 template it uses is quite standard and can easily be modified if necessary.